# Appending a string to baseURL protractor Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor

I have defined baseURL in my Config file. I have 5 different specs running at the same time with baseURL+ different GUID.

Currently, I have this in my each of my spec. 
//The below one navigates to the Home Page for my credentials.

```
 it('Should enter homepage url and credentials', function() {
      browser.get('/#/');

      });
```

// Using the Override to view Customer information. Hence passing the URL/CustomerGuid as soon as the login is successful

```
it ('Should get Customer GUID', function() {
        browser.get('https://my-testlink-test.com/?CustomerGUID=123456789#/');//Test
    //browser.get('https://my-testlink.com/?CustomerGUID=123456789#/');//Production
          expect(....)

    });
```

Is there a way to append baseURL to different GUIDs when we call browser.get?

I tried the following but it doesn't work. Each time I switch between environments, I go back and change the url in all the different 5 spec to -test or production URL.

browser.get('#'+'GUID') // getting baseURL and appending to customer GUID

Comment: Have you tried to start with slash: `browser.get("/?CustomerGUID=123456789#/")`?

Comment: It worked. Thanks so much. I researched online but I couldn't find this info anywhere. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Protractor will automatically append relative paths to the baseUrl for you. This can be especially handy when using page object.

conf.js

```
baseUrl: 'https://my-testlink-test.com/',
```

customerPage.js

```
this.url = '?CustomerGUID=123456789#/';
```

spec.js

```
browser.get(customerPage.url);
```